# Fastboot setserial command

Tags: fastboot

I noticed that a lot of descriptions of fastboot mention a command named `setserial` which not available in the current version that comes with Android SDK.

You can see the complete list of commands including setserial, for example [here](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=Fastboot#Fastboot_Commands). The missing setserial command is not the only command missing in the current version.
The setserial command sounds very interesting for some tests I want to perform.

**Does anybody has experience with that command and know where to get a fastboot binary that supports it?**

Furthermore it would be interesting if current Android devices still allow to change the serial - may be this was only possible on the G1 and Nexus One?

Comment: I am not 100% sure if the serial can be changed! Some boot images would have a serial number in place, but then again, if the serial number is changed, the system would not recognize it and possibly trigger a re-install of the usb drivers....

Answer (score 1):

The option has been moved to the `oem` subset of fastboot functions. Since every vendor is using their own proprietary ways to handle serial numbers. So there is no universal solution available. It is not a matter of finding a "fastboot binary that supports it". Fastboot binary  just sends commands to the device's bootloader. And "setserial" commands are proprietary.

Comment: What about the bootloaders used on Google Nexus devices? Do you know any details about the setserial command for those?

Comment: Nexus devices are designed by different OEMs and are not much different in this regard.